# Visual Studio Code Chinese Character problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The interface of VSCode is all in English. However, when I compiled my C++ project, I found some Chinese words appeared in `launch.json` and `tasks.json`. I didn't download any Chinese extensions. I tried to uninstall all extensions and reinstall VSCode, But nothing worked for me. What's the problem? And how can I solve it?

[image: Problem 1]
[image: Problem 2]

Versions:
Software: Visual Studio Code 1.71.0
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Is your Windows localized as Chinese? May we assume that those Chinese words are descriptions of the tasks?

Comment: It certainly looks like VSCode noted that Windows is using Chinese, and made the task descriptions in Chinese accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, my Windows localized as Chinese. But can I turn these chinese words into English and my windows still localize as Chinese?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem by changing my Windows default language setting!